# How do I select (checkbox) a value from a vuetify multiselect v-autocomplete in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js, v-autocomplete

I have a multi select v-autocomplete component from vuetify.js and the items are an array that get used in the multi select dropdown

The defendantCodeOptions items look like this

```
{text: "some text", value: 36}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to select items in javascript that are returned from a ajax call.

```js
<v-autocomplete 
v-model = "defendantCode"
label = "Defendant Code"
:items = "defendantCodeOptions"
:loading = "defendantCodeIsLoading"
:filter = "customFilter"
clearable
multiple
dense >
</v-autocomplete>
```

ex. I want to loop through each item from a ajax calls response like this below and set each checked values in the dropdown to the ones that match the values from the server. But this below isn't working!

```js
// returned values from ajax call
what I want is something like this
for (var i = 0; i < all items; i++) {
  // if the value of this item exists in any of the returned values, check it
 }
```

I want it to look like this using code behind and NOT the UI

[image]

Comment: v-model is linked to defendantCode so I would guess that setting `this.defendantCode = 3` would do it?

Comment: In your for loop you are just changing the value of defendantCode on each iteration of the loop.  But I think what you want to do is change the value of each item in the drop down, correct?

Comment: Maybe you can provide an example or screenshot of the end-state?

Comment: I updated my post again to show more details

Comment: One question - if I just wanted to run through each item from the drop down and mark it as "checked" how would I do that?

Comment: So if it's a multi-select, then it looks like this.defendantCode should start out as an array and you need to push the values into it.

Comment: yes it is a multiselect. But it's the defendantCodeOptions that is the array, not defendantCode. And each item in the array is a text/value pair.

Comment: defendantCode is linked via v-model so the values in defendantCode should set selected options in defendantCodeOptions. That's how it works with a simple Vue select anyway. It looks similair in this example from Vuetify: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/examples/autocompletes/intermediate/slots.vue

Comment: To elaborate on ezero, and correct me if I'm wrong: if you have this: `this.defendantCodeOptions = [{text: "some text", value: 36}, {text: "some other text", value: 63}]` . Then in the for loop do `this.defendantCodeOptions.push(valueFromLoop[i]);`  assuming your value is in the format `{text: <str>, value: <int>}`.

Comment: I just updated my post

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct answer.

```
this.defendantCode = [3, 4]
```